# перенос строки android java

Tags: java, android

Собираю данные с сайта и вывожу их в формате `json`, пример: `$responsetableldoljnost[$dd4].' \n ';`

Парсинг:

```
String pars1 = object.getString("000");
```

Вывод данных:

```
TextView edpars1 = findViewById(R.id.edpars1);
edpars1.setText(pars1);
```

Как сделать так чтобы где есть в тексте элемент `\n` строка переносилась?
Сейчас выводит:

> блабла \n блабла бла \n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так попробуй

```
edpars1.setText(pars1.replace("\\n","\n"));
```